# Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, yarl

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I am trying to make a discord bot with nextcord, but when I try to install it using command prompt, it gives me this error:

```
 × Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      C:\Users\klama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pknvci1v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      **********************
      * Accelerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      running build_ext
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried updating my pip, but it says "Requirement already satisfied". I've been looking for about 2 hours an a half and still can't find it.

Comment: Consider reading the error. It says `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Answer (score 0):

Just instal python 3.10. I tried instal Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0... did not work out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted says it all: you need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater.

For those of you here because you got this error after updating your Python Docker image to Python 3.11, it may be because `gcc` and other C++ libraries aren't included in the image anymore. For example, this can be fixed in `3.11.0-slim-buster` by adding the following line to your `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```